# How many rides completed on average in a 4 hour span

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset:

```
ride_completion_time    ride_id
0   2022-08-27 11:42:02 1
1   2022-08-24 05:59:26 2
2   2022-08-23 17:40:05 3
3   2022-08-28 23:06:01 4
4   2022-08-27 03:21:29 5
```

I would like to find out in a 4 hour time span, on average, how many rides are actually completed?
I run `df3.dtypes` to get my data types.

output:

```
dropoff_datetime    datetime64[ns]
ride_id                     object
dtype: object
```

**Then I've tried the following:**

Option 1)

```
df3 = df3.groupby(df3.ride_completion_time.dt.floor('2H')).mean()
```

Result: Dataframe object has no attribute dropoff_date_time

Option 2)

```
df3.groupby(df3.index.floor('4H').time).sum()
```

Result: It gives me the right grouping (I see that it's changing my times to every 4 hours) but then it's not summing it really? I tried using average but average isn't supported I think.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: the syntax you provided does not match the tags. Can you update your question with the SQL statements you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

`ride_id` is object type (probably string) so `sum` and `mean` would exclude this column. You want to know number of rides, you can do `size`:

```
df3.groupby(df3.index.floor('4H').time).size()
```

As to why 2) works but not 1), probably somewhere you set `ride_completion_time` as index in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works but my total rides in my data frame is 100278. However, when I run the code, I get 

 
00:00:00 8
04:00:00 7
08:00:00 7
12:00:00 7
16:00:00 7
20:00:00 8